# Reading data from firebase functions

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've now spent the better part of 16 hours tearing my hair out over javascript, so I figured it was time to ask someone.

I have an android app made in android studio, which is connected to a firebase database that looks roughly like this:

```
nameOfDatabase
    Places
        Bar
            B001
                place_ID_ : "B001"
                ...
                average_rating_ : 0
                ...
                number_of_ratings_ : 0

            ...other bars

        ...other place types  

    Ratings
        ratingID1
            place_ID_ : "B001"
            rating_ : 3
            user_ID_ : 4315732985097

            ...other parameters

        ...other ratings
```

What I want to do is simply update the number_of_ratings_ and average_ratings_ for the place matching the place_ID_ whenever a rating_ changes, either by an existing value being modified or a new Rating being added. My index.js code for the firebase functions node module looks like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.UpdateAverageRatings = functions.database.ref('/Ratings/{rating_uid}/rating_').onWrite(event => {

    let place_ID_ = admin.database().ref('Ratings/' + String(event.params.rating_uid) + '/place_ID_').val();

    console.log(place_ID_);

    let place_type_ = 'BARs';
    let place_ID_ = 'B001';
    let avg_rating_ = 0;
    let accumulated_rating_ = 0;
    let number_of_ratings_ = 0;

    //Object.keys(place_ID_.parent).forEach(function(key) {
    //    if (place_ID_.parent[key] == 'place_ID_'){
    //        accumulated_rating_ += place_ID_.parent[key].value();
    //        number_of_ratings_ += 1;
    //}});

    let place_change_ = admin.database().ref('Places/' + String(place_type_) + '/' +String(place_ID_));

    place_change_.child('average_rating_').set(avg_rating_);
    place_change_.child('number_of_ratings_').set(number_of_ratings_);

    return 0;

  });
```

Setting the values, in the last two lines before return, works as it should, but for now I'm just setting the dummy values '0'. An idea for assigning the correct values is commented out for later use.

**The problem is that whatever I try, I can't seem to read any values from the database, as seen attempted in the 'let place_ID_ ...' line and subsequent console log.**

I've read through the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) and stackexchange posts countless times, but I either get

"TypeError: admin.database(...).ref(...).val is not a function"

in the firebase console logs , or if I remove val();

```
W {
  u: 
   dh {
     app: 
      FirebaseApp {
        firebaseInternals_: [Object],
        services_: [Object],
        isDeleted_: false,
        name_: '[DEFAULT]',
        options_: [Object],
        database: [Function: bound ],
        INTERNAL: [Object] },
     L: 
      Tb {
        host: 'projectname.firebaseio.com',
        domain: 'firebaseio.com',
        Pc: true,
        ne: 'projectname',
        tg: false,
        ef: '',
        Za: 'projectname.firebaseio.com' },
     Ua: Ff { qc: {} },
     Sc: null,
     ca: he { tb: [] },
     td: 1,
     Qa: 
      kh {
        id: 0,
        f: [Function],
        nd: {},
        '$': {},
        pa: [],
        Lc: 0,
        Hc: [],
        ma: false,
        Ra: 1000,
        qd: 300000,
        Eb: [Function: bound ],
        Gc: [Function: bound ],
        se: [Function: bound ],
        L: [Object],
        xe: null,
        Ab: null,
        Ea: null,
        mb: null,
        Xc: [Object],
        ae: false,
        he: 0,
        Rd: undefined,
        sb: [Object],
        Kb: true,
        Ed: {},
        kg: 0,
        Oe: true,
        je: null,
        xc: null },
     va: 
      kh {
        id: 0,
        f: [Function],
        nd: {},
        '$': {},
        pa: [],
        Lc: 0,
        Hc: [],
        ma: false,
        Ra: 1000,
        qd: 300000,
        Eb: [Function: bound ],
        Gc: [Function: bound ],
        se: [Function: bound ],
        L: [Object],
        xe: null,
        Ab: null,
        Ea: null,
        mb: null,
        Xc: [Object],
        ae: false,
        he: 0,
        Rd: undefined,
        sb: [Object],
        Kb: true,
        Ed: {},
        kg: 0,
        Oe: true,
        je: null,
        xc: null },
     qg: Df { qf: {}, Sc: [Object], va: [Object] },
     jc: Vc { sd: '', Mc: null, A: [Object] },
     fe: Nb { Hd: [Object] },
     md: Dg { wa: [Object], hb: [Object], Be: {}, fc: {}, zc: [Object] },
     ia: Eb { B: null, k: null },
     Xa: ch { ta: [Circular], ba: [Object], INTERNAL: [Object] },
     cd: 0,
     ge: null,
     K: Dg { wa: [Object], hb: [Object], Be: {}, fc: {}, zc: [Object] } },
  path: G { o: [ 'Ratings', 'ratingID1', 'place_ID_' ], Y: 0 },
  m: 
   jf {
     xa: false,
     ka: false,
     Ib: false,
     na: false,
     Pb: false,
     oa: 0,
     kb: '',
     bc: null,
     xb: '',
     Zb: null,
     vb: '',
     g: Ae {} },
  Kc: false,
  then: undefined,
  catch: undefined }
```

, which is rather incredible given that this database key only holds an integer value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I can provide more information if necessary.

**Edit**
I've now tried using the async/await keywords coupled with once('value).then(snapshot => snapshot.val()) to get the value, but this does not compile, or if I remove async/await, the promise never resolves.

Answer (score 2):

Retrieving a value from the database is async.

If you look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write it has an example of retrieving a value once:

> ```
> var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
> return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
>   var username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().username) || 'Anonymous';
>   // ...
> });
> ```

You either use `on('value')` for receiving updates to the value, or `once('value')` for getting it once. Both return a promise which passes a `snapshot`, and `snapshot.val()` will give you the value at that node.

Thus you can retrieve the value like so:

```
const place_ID_ = await admin.database().ref(`Ratings/${event.params.rating_uid}/place_ID_`).once('value').then(snapshot => snapshot.val());
console.log('place_ID_:', place_ID_);
```

Psst, all those underscores are terribly ugly just saying, try camelCase ;) And you don't need to wrap variables in `String()` if they're already strings, or you're concatenating with other strings. And you can use `const` for variables which don't change rather than `let`.

Comment: If I use await, it won't compile at all, so I tried without it. In that case it just ouputs a pending promise. I then tried  .then(snapshot => snapshot.val()).then(console.log(snapshot)), and this gives a Reference Error ("snapshot" is not defined at exports).

Comment: Using 'Ratings/${event.params.rating_uid}/ instead of 'Ratings/' + String(event.params.rating_uid) + '/' makes the database unable to update the values later, which was the only part that worked previously, so these are not equivalent operations.

Comment: They are equivalent look up es6 strings and make sure you're using backticks not quotes. Your parent function needs to have `async` before the `function` keyword. Or you can just work with the promise directly like in firebase's example

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: There is no function keyword anywhere in index.js for firebase projects, only functions.database.ref... I tried adding async before this line anyway, but it won't compile ("Unexpected identifier", probably the async). Is there no other way in javascript of waiting for async tasks to complete?

Comment: You are calling that code in a function, if you use `await` in a function you need to declare it as asyc. It's nothing to do with firebase https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: FYI, on() does not return a promise. It stays listening until the listener gets removed.  Also, there's almost no reason to use on() in Cloud Functions.  Nearly all applications will want to use once().

Comment: As written in the edit, I've used once('value).then(snapshot => snapshot.val()), but this promise never resolves. I didn't use on()